# Scrolling button jQuery doesn't work instantly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on some web pages that use a button to scroll to the next div. I can get it to work on every page, except in this particular instance (see jsfiddle).

My problem is that the buttons don't work on loading the page, the user first has to start scrolling manually, before the buttons work. I'm assuming that's because of some fault in my jQuery coding, which I've looked over and over, but I can't seem to find the problem. Is there anyone who is a bit more familiar with jQuery than I am who can offer me a solution?

http://jsfiddle.net/y5wx7nst/3/

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

var currentElement = $("#bodytext > div:nth-child(1)");

var onScroll = function () {
    var container = $("#bodytext");
    var children = $(".section");
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        var child = $(children[i]);
        var childLeft = container.offset().left < child.offset().left;
        if (childLeft) {
            currentElement = child;
            console.log(currentElement);
            return;
        }
    }
};

var scrollToElement = function ($element) {
    var container = $("#bodytext");
    var children = $(".section");
    var width = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        var child = $(children[i]);
        if (child.get(0) == $element.get(0)) {
            if (i === 0) {
                width = 0;
            }
            container.animate({
                scrollLeft: width
            }, 500);
            onScroll();
        }
        if (child.next().length > 0) {
            width += child.next().offset().left - child.offset().left;
        } else {
            width += child.width();
        }
    }
};

var buttonright = function (e) {
        scrollToElement(currentElement.next());
    };

var buttonleft = function (e) {
    var container = $("#bodytext");
    if (currentElement.prev().length > 0) {
        if (container.offset().left == currentElement.prev().offset().left) {
            currentElement = currentElement.prev().prev().length > 0 ? currentElement.prev().prev() : currentElement.prev();
        } else {
            currentElement = currentElement.prev();
        }
    }
    scrollToElement(currentElement);
};

$("#bodytext").scroll(onScroll);
$("#buttonright").click(buttonright);
$("#buttonleft").click(buttonleft);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only calling the onScroll() function after you initially scroll:

```
$("#bodytext").scroll(onScroll);
```

I added this before that declaration and it all worked:

```
onScroll();
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y5wx7nst/5/

Comment: Thank you so much for that, saved my life. I knew there was a very easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

When code run value of currentElement is not correct. So you should calculate it calling a function onScroll();

```
...
$("#bodytext").scroll(onScroll);
$("#buttonright").click(buttonright);
$("#buttonleft").click(buttonleft);
onScroll();
});
```