# jQuery animate scrollLeft stops working after several clicks in FF and Chrome (but not Safari)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, scroll, jquery-animate

I have a very strange problem with some jquery code that scrolls a group of images. It seems to work in all browsers for the first several clicks, advancing the images by a number. And in Safari, it will work perfectly all the way to the end of the slideshow. But in FF and Chrome it will stop after a certain number of images. And this number is NOT always the same for some reason.

For example, on [this](http://abmoarchitects.com/project/nopalito-2/) page FF/Chrome will stop after clicking the next arrow 7 times.

And on [this](http://abmoarchitects.com/project/soma-eats/) page, FF/Chrome will stop after clicking the next arrow 6 times.

Yet on [this](http://abmoarchitects.com/project/verbena/) page, FF/Chrome will work all the way to the end as expected (and as Safari does all the time).

This is the code that controls the clicking:

```
<script>$(window).load(function(){
var currentElement = $("#ngg-gallery-list > div:nth-child(2)");
var onScroll = function () {
    //get the current element
    var container = $("#ngg-galleryoverview");
    var wrapper = $("#ngg-gallery-list");
    var children = wrapper.children();
    var position = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        var child = $(children[i]);
        var childLeft = container.offset().left < child.offset().left;
        if (childLeft) {
            currentElement = child;
            return;
        }
    }
}

var scrollToElement = function ($element) {
    var container = $("#ngg-galleryoverview");
    var wrapper = $("#ngg-gallery-list");
    var children = wrapper.children();
    var width = 0;
    console.log(children.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        var child = $(children[i]);

        if (child.get(0) == $element.get(0)) {
            if (i == 0) {
                width = 300;
            }
            container.animate({
                scrollLeft: width
            }, 300);
            onScroll();
        }
        if (child.next().length > 0) {

            //make sure we factor in borders/padding/margin in height
            width += child.next().offset().left - child.offset().left
        } else {
            width += child.width();

        }
    }
}

var next = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    scrollToElement(currentElement);
}

var prev = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var container = $("#ngg-galleryoverview");
    if (currentElement.prev().length > 0) {
        if (container.offset().left == currentElement.prev().offset().left) {
            currentElement = currentElement.prev().prev().length > 0 ? currentElement.prev().prev() : currentElement.prev();
        } else {
            currentElement = currentElement.prev();
        }
    }
    scrollToElement(currentElement);
}

$("#ngg-galleryoverview").on('scroll', onScroll);
$("#nexty").click(next);
$("#prevy").click(prev);
});
</script>
```

I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, making my code look more like what I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378433/scrolling-button-jquery-doesnt-work-instantly) fixed the problem. (Even if I am not entirely sure why). Hoping it helps someone else, here is the final code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

var currentElement = $("#ngg-galleryoverview > div:nth-child(1)");

var onScroll = function () {
    var container = $("#ngg-galleryoverview");
    var children = $(".list");
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        var child = $(children[i]);
        var childLeft = container.offset().left < child.offset().left;
        if (childLeft) {
            currentElement = child;
            //console.log(currentElement);
            return;
        }
    }
};

var scrollToElement = function ($element) {
    var container = $("#ngg-galleryoverview");
    var children = $(".list");
    var width = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        var child = $(children[i]);
        if (child.get(0) == $element.get(0)) {
            if (i === 0) {
                width = 0;
            }
            container.animate({
                scrollLeft: width
            }, 500);
            onScroll();
        }
        if (child.next().length > 0) {
            width += child.next().offset().left - child.offset().left;
        } else {
            width += child.width();
        }
    }
};

var buttonright = function (e) {
        scrollToElement(currentElement.next());
    };

var buttonleft = function (e) {
    var container = $("#ngg-galleryoverview");
    if (currentElement.prev().length > 0) {
        if (container.offset().left == currentElement.prev().offset().left) {
            currentElement = currentElement.prev().prev().length > 0 ? currentElement.prev().prev() : currentElement.prev();
        } else {
            currentElement = currentElement.prev();
        }
    }
    scrollToElement(currentElement);
};

    onScroll();
$("#ngg-galleryoverview").scroll(onScroll);
$("#nexty").click(buttonright);
$("#prevy").click(buttonleft);

});</script>
```